# how to unlink file in php after ajax callback is received

Tags: php, ajax, response, unlink

For creating a `.zip` file, i send the response back to ajax.

My php

```
// Multiple download (checkboxes)
if(isset($_POST["checkboxes_down"])) { 

    // create a tmp folder for the zip file
    $tmpfolder = $MainFolderName.'/tmpzip';
    if (!is_dir($tmpfolder)) {
         mkdir($tmpfolder, 0755, true);
    }

    $checkboxfiles = explode("," , $_POST["checkboxes_down"]); 
    $filename = "archive.zip";
    $filepath = $tmpfolder."/";

    foreach($checkboxfiles as $checkboxfile) {              
        Zip($checkboxfile, $tmpfolder."/archive.zip");
    }   

    // send the path to file back as response
    echo $filepath.$filename;

    unlink($tmpfolder.'/archive.zip'); // unlink archive.zip            
    rmdir($tmpfolder); // remove tmpdir
    exit;

}
```

my jquery ajax:

```
 $.ajax({  
            url:"",                                 
            method:"POST",  

            data:{ checkboxes_down:checkboxes_down },  
            success:function(response){                                 
               window.location = response; // redirec to .zip file for download
            }
```

I was hoping that the response and redirect was quicker then the unlink from the tmpfolder. But unfortunately, i can not use the `unlink` the way i created it in the php file.

So how can i unlink the `tmpfolder` after response is successful and redirected?Should i use something as a delay before unlinking?

Comment: If you are trying to redirect to the zip file? Why do you want to delete it. There will be nothing to redirect to??

Comment: What you're doing is: AJAX HTTP POST request → create ZIP, destroy ZIP, return path (to non-existent ZIP) → HTTP response → HTTP GET request to non-existent ZIP. Instead you should make one HTTP POST request (not AJAX), and output the ZIP straight to `php://output`, without even writing it to disk.

Comment: @Riggs my logic is: redirect to the .zip file to download. After download, immediately remove the tmpfolder. Because it is unnecessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option would be to scrap Ajax, use a regular form submission, and then output the zip file directly as the response instead of writing a file to disk.